# how to use Route::input in laravel4?

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to use Laravel 4 method called **Route:input("users").** But I am getting following error

**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Router::input()**

Any idea how Route::input() works. Is there any file I need to change.

Thanks all

Comment: ya, i am using  Route::input('users') only.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::filter('userFilter', function () {
    if (Route::input('name') == 'John') {
        return 'Welcome John.';
    }
});

Route::get('user/{name}', array(
    'before' => 'userFilter',
    function ($name) {
    return 'Hello, you are not John.';
}));
```

Comment: This may resolve the issue, but code only answers don't help people as much as those which also explain why they resolve the issue

Answer (score -1):

It looks as though Route::input was added in Laravel 4.1, make sure this is the version you are working with if you need to use this functionality.

I assume you've read the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters), but since you asked how it works, here's the example:

```
Accessing A Route Parameter Value

If you need to access a route parameter value outside of a route, you may use the Route::input method:

Route::filter('foo', function()
{
    // Do something with Route::input('users');
});
```

Comment: This is copy-pasted from the docs, and therefore useless. Does not answer the question at all.

Comment: I have said it's an example from the docs - showing him how it works and haven't claimed otherwise. The example shows how you would use Router::input(). Also, the error message he mentioned might suggest it's not available in the version of Laravel used.

Comment: I actually found this page because I was also looking for an example of how to use the Route::input function. Unfortunately, the example given in the docs is only one small example, that doesn't cover a fraction of possible use cases. For instance, how does it interact with parameters? Is Route::input pulling from the url or just the Input facade? Can it be used as part of a controller? Or does it only work in the filter method? Just linking to the docs is not helpful, unless you can also add something that isn't written there.

Comment: Fair enough but these are questions are *yours* not those of the original poster who didn't specify a specific use case, thus an initial link to the docs (which a lot of people fail to check before posting on SO) was presented. The questioner appears not to have done much research hence my answer pointing them in the right direction seems appropriate.

Comment: I agree that the initial posted did not ask a very good question, and that my specific use case is not really relevant. However, I feel that the purpose of posting an answer on stack overflow is not just to help the one person asking the question, but also the many other people searching similar/related issues. Posting a link to the docs may help this one person, but it won't benefit the people who come later.

Comment: Op asked how `Route::input()` works; pointing to the docs does not help them, or anyone else, understand how it works, it just shows one small example of how it can be used. That's technically correct, but completely useless.

Comment: So you expect me to be able to read your mind or look into the future? Utterly stupid comment. The answer is just that; an answer to the original question, not your question, which btw you haven't asked. Down vote if you want, couldn't care less but frankly your reasoning is moronic. I've already explained why I gave a link to the docs, won't repeat myself or read your future comments on this ticket as it's pointless.